# Search mySQL database by name using Google Maps API v3

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I currently created a locator using Google Maps API v3. It searches for locations stored in a database.

These locations have names. I'd like to tie in a search function that searches the database by name OR by location. I have looked through the Google Places API, but I'm not sure where to apply this sort of text searching function. I haven't seen a good example yet of how to do this or if it is even possible.

Any suggestions or advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Language - PHP

Comment: I currently have it set up using php

Comment: query the database for the name and send the corresponding coords to the API

Comment: something along the lines of:  OR name ='user input name'

Comment: So I would query for the name first? Then use that result as the name portion for the query that goes to the API? Here is a link to my code that has the query http://pastebin.com/YRXZG3YX @Randy

Answer (score 0):

Your pastebin uses the deprecated **[mysql_ extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)**. For new code you should use either **[MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**. The following code uses PDO

```
try {
    //Connect to database
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    // Prepare statement 1
    $searchStmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT lat,lng FROM markers WHERE name LIKE ? ");
    // Assign parameters
    $searchStmt->bindParam(1,$name);
    $searchStmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $searchStmt->execute();
    $row = $searchStmt->fetch();
    $center_lat = $row['lat'];
    $center_lng = $row['lng'];
    // Start XML file, create parent node
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
    // Prepare statement 2
    $markerStmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");
    // Assign parameters
    $markerStmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);
    $markerStmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);
    $markerStmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
    $markerStmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
    //Execute query
    $markerStmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $markerStmt->execute();
    //Default for zero rows
    if ($markerStmt->rowCount()==0) {
        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name", "No Records Found");
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $center_lat);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $center_lng);
        $newnode->setAttribute("distance", 0);
                }
    else {
    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while($row = $markerStmt->fetch()) {
        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
        }
    }
echo $dom->saveXML();

}


catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", mapSelect.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
 }
//Close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

`$searchStmt` searches the database for name. It uses the coordinates found for `$markerStmt`.

```
if ($markerStmt->rowCount()==0) {
...
}
```

Is used to provide a marker in the search location if no records found.